# How to build maven artifact that run test suites? How 'sbt test' works?

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I'm scala developer, so i'll try to explain my thoughts with sbt example but i belive java developers can understand me

Traditional scala/java project structure is like follow:

```
src ->
 - main
 - test
 - it
```

test folder is conceptually for unit testing (for testing app logic). So you can run 'sbt test' and will test over your application. This code must be close to your application.

may be that was offtopic, here is my question:

is it possible to build jar artifact that would run all my tests? I don't want to start sbt just in order to run my tests. I want to build many jar artifacts with integration test suites

```
java my-super-service-it-case1.jar
```

this would give me exit code 0 if tests have passed

```
java my-super-service-it-case2.jar
```

so on...

I belive i need to run test within main block..

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend to mix any of your tests within the main functionality of your program, there is a very good plugin for exactly what you want to do, [Maven Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/index.html) and it should be working fine with Scala but have not ever messed around with Scala my self.

It would be to much to write out what you need here but it's well covered in the documentation and a lot of examples. You can specify different goals which has includes and excludes so you can for example just execute Unit tests or Acceptance Tests with for example:

```
mvn verify -P acceptance-tests -Dbuild.env=sit
```

Which has following profile configured in the `POM.XML` file

```
<profile>
  <id>acceptance-tests</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>env.BUILD_STAGE</name>
      <value>ACCEPTANCE</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- skip unit tests -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- run acceptance tests (during integration-test phase) -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*AT*.*</include>
          </includes>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*Test.*</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*IT.*</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

All my Acceptance Tests are named with AT like, myTestAT.java